# how to pass object parameters using route() method in laravel5.4

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-5.4

i have a blade that should send id to controller for sorting
i just wanted to try a route with simple parameter to just see what happen **but i'm getting error :(**

this is my route call in blade

```
<a href="{{ route('sortby_followers' , ['id' => 8]) }}" > click </a>
```

this is my web.php

```
 Route::get('/sortby=followers/{id}' , [
    'uses' => 'PageController@sortby_followers',
    'as' => 'sortby_followers'
]);
```

and in controller code

```
 public function sortby_followers($id)
 {
    dd($id);
 }
```

but i got this error

> Missing required parameters for [Route: sortby_followers] [URI:
>   sortby=followers/ali/ghasem/{id}]. (View:
>   C:\wamp64\www\insta\resources\views\admin\r_pages\shop\product.blade.php)

i just wanted to see what happen and now i didn't route with object parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**try this one**

use `/sortby_followers/{id}` instead of `/sortby=followers/{id}` otherwise use like that

in blade use like that

```
<a href="{{ route('sortby_followers' , 8) }}">click</a>
```

in web

```
Route::get('/sortby_followers/{id}' ,'PageController@sortby_followers');
```

in controller

```
public function sortby_followers($id)
{
    dd($id);
}
```

Comment: @Rezash add here bro

Answer (score 0):

Just change your route only in `web.php`

`/sortby=followers/{id}` with `/sortby_followers/{id}`

```
Route::get('/sortby_followers/{id}' , [
                    'uses' => 'PageController@sortby_followers',
                    'as' => 'sortby_followers'
                  ]);
```

And also change your web link:

```
<a href="{{route('sortby_followers' , [8])}}" >click</a>
```

Comment: I have tested it working for me, you're missing something else. Check your routes setup again. It should work.